# How to authenticate PowerBI embedded with OKTA

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, okta, powerbi-embedded, okta-api

I have a sample ASPNETCore application that authenticates with OKTA (code repo here: https://github.com/ramicodes/Okta-netcore-auth-sample)

I want to use powerbi embedded (user owns data scenario) but i need to use OKTA for authentication. PowerBI is already working and configured to authenticate with OKTA through Azure AD.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved.
User owns data scenario, means that the user that is signed in to PowerBI.com successfully, can see the same artifacts in an embedded scenario.

If you're claiming to have successfully authenticated your users against PowerBI.com, then it should work, otherwise, I'd recommend using 'App owns data' for custom auth.